# How to use a file chooser in Django?

Tags: django, filechooser

What I need is a button that I open the file explorer, select the file and then show the path of the file. What I've seen so far requires uploading the file and I just need the get the path. Is there another way that doesn't require uploading the file or it only can be managed like that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make your good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `<input type="file"/>` will provide the functionality you seek. However the full file path is typically unavailable. Modern browsers replace it with `C:\fakepath\<file>` as revealing information on the web, such as directories, about the clients machine is a security problem if the site was infected by XSS (Cross-Site Scripting).

Comment: I didn't know about the fakepath, but thank you for your help.